# How to download SSH keys in Debian on GCP?

Tags: debian, ssh-keys, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to download my SSH keys so that I can use Filezilla to connect to my webserver. This SHOULD be pretty straightforward - but everything I've tried has failed.

I currently have access to the etc/ssh directory through an SSH connection. I can see the files the folder - but I'm unclear which one is the correct key file.

Secondly, how do I download a file through terminal from SSH?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions. You've already been given answers to these questions in a previous question you posted.

Comment: Sorry - I somehow forgot about the other post. Thanks for linking it.